# How to resolve a promise with two values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Consider the following code:

```
new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    res('a','b')
}).then(function (a, b) {
    console.log(a,b)
})
```

It outputs

```
a undefined
```

How can I resolve return the two values out of the Promise?

Comment: With an array ?

Comment: or object... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return them in an array.

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res(["a", "b"]);
}).then(([a, b]) => {
  console.log(a, b);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot, a promise fulfills or rejects with exactly one value.

It's trivial however to put the two values in a structure, such as an array:

```
new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(['a','b'])
}).then(function([a, b]) { // array destructuring
    console.log(a, b)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    res(['a','b'])
}).then(function (resContent) {
    console.log(...resContent)
})
```

It outputs

```
a b
```